# java switch case question

Tags: java

```
public String sizeOfSupermarket() {
    String size;
    switch (this.numberOfProducts) {
        case (this.numberOfProducts >  5000):
            size = "Large";
            break;
        case (this.numberOfProducts >  2000 && this.numberOfProducts < 5000):
            size = "Medium";
            break;
        case (this.numberOfProducts <  2000):
            size = "Small";
            break;
    }
    return size;
}
```

the above is wrong, how to write the compare statement in  case statement?

Comment: you need `if` statement. No switch

Comment: What will you return if `size` is 5000 or 2000?

Comment: this is a very funny codes :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a derived value, in this case look at the number of thousands.

```
public String sizeOfSupermarket() {
    switch (this.numberOfProducts/1000) {
        case 0: case 1: return "Small";
        case 2: case 3: case 4: return "Medium";
        default: return "Large";
    }
}
```

Note: you have a bug in your code such that if the numberOfProducts is exactly 2000 or 5000, it will return null (assuming it compiled)

Answer (score 1):

You can't use expressions in `case` statements. The condition is evaluated by the `switch` statement, and the `case` statements check if the result matches.

To do what you are trying to do, you will have to use a series of `if` and `else if` statements:

```
if(this.numberOfProducts > 5000) {
    size = "Large";  
}
else if(this.numberOfProducts > 2000 && this.numberOfProducts < 5000) {
    size = "Medium";
}
else {
   size = "Small";
}
```

Comment: if i must use switch case? can i?

Comment: Not if you want to use an expression for each case. As stated by the 8 answers you've already got, you can only use if/else statements for that. The whole point of a `switch` is that the condition is evaluated in the `switch`, and the `case`s are tested for a match.

Comment: you don't handle the case where `numberOfProducts == 5000` see @Gabriel's answer, you don't need the extra check.

Comment: @hkvega, you can, see my answer.

Comment: @Peter - I didn't handle that case because it wasn't handled by the OP. I probably shouldn't have handled the case when `numberOfProducts == 2000` either, but `else` was quicker to type than another `else if`!

Answer (score 1):

```
if (numberOfProducts >= 5000)
    size = "Large";
else if (numberOfProducts >= 2000)
    size = "Medium";
else
    size = "Small";
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use switch to test for boolean expressions. You need to use if.
You can use switch if you want to check if a variable has one certain value, i.e.:

```
public String sizeOfSupermarket() {
String size;
switch (this.numberOfProducts) {
    case 5000:
        size = "Large";
        break;
    case 2000:
        size = "Medium";
        break;
    case 100):
        size = "Small";
        break;
    }
    return size;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java 1.6 does not support a conditional switch statement, your best bet would be to use the if then else control structure

Answer (score 0):

No way. By definition switch/case is based on enumerated types only (int, boolean, long, enum) in all C-like languages I know.

So you have to use if/else structure here:

```
public String sizeOfSupermarket() {
    String size;
        if (this.numberOfProducts >  5000) {
            size = "Large";
        } else if (this.numberOfProducts >  2000 && this.numberOfProducts < 5000) {
            size = "Medium";
        } else (this.numberOfProducts <  2000) {
            size = "Small";
        }
    return size;
}
```